# where did the configuration file stored in CDH4

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, cloudera-manager

I setup a CDH4
Now I can configure the hadoop on the web page.

I want to know where did the cdh put the configuration file on the local file system.

for example, I want to find the core-site.xml, but where is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the installation of CDH has the `conf` directory located in

```
/etc/hadoop/
```

You could always use the following command to find the file:

```
$ sudo find / -name "core-site.xml"
```

Comment: Thx, I found it. I did found it before, because I did not finish the installation of CDH.

Comment: There are multiple copies of the core-site.xml in a particular node. More information [here](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/07/how-does-cloudera-manager-work/).